# PHP URL Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have a url like this.

```
http://www.somesite.com/community.php?id=4
```

for id number 4 would equal Washington
  for id number 5 would equal Denver
  for id number 6 would equal New York

I would like the url to be rewritten like this.

```
http://www.somesite.com/washington  for id = 4
http://www.somesite.com/denver for id = 5
```

is this possible?

How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at mod_rewrite: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

You can, for example, do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule washington community.php?id=4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule denver community.php?id=5 [L,QSA]
```

This would, of course, lead to a LOT of rewrite rules if you have much cities. So, a IMHO smarter way would be to rewrite the URI slug to community.php and lookup the ID from some sort of database:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCOnd %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?([a-z-]+) community.php?city=$1 [L,QSA]
```

HTH

Comment: i think the first example will work.  Its a list, not a long one.

I think stackoverflow should allow people to put in monies for credits and xfer credits to people who respond with good / right answers (imho)