# Rewriting a static URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I want to do is change the URL of `www.abc.com/test.html` to `www.abc.com/context/`

I dont know, if this is even possible. Like, I have seen dynamic URLs being changed, but I have no idea if this possible. I tried search engines but all are helping with converting dynamic URLs.

Please guide me with one idea, and maybe I can proceed with others.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am working on a simple static HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930849/php-url-rewrite have you read this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create .htaccess with the following rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    # if you are working on a localhost change RewriteBase /example-folder-name/
RewriteRule ^context(.*) test.html
```

Comment: This is not working somehow. Maybe, I am going wrong somewhere.
How I wrote is:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wpx/    # if you are working on a localhost change RewriteBase /example-folder-name/
RewriteRule ^context/$ /test.html [L]`

I just changed the Rewrite Base to `/wpx/`

Comment: Also, I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error on working with the answer provided by Avin and Sudip

Comment: What is the url you are trying. @ankitjain11

Comment: .htaccess must be in root folder. @ankitjain11

Comment: I am working in localhost and the .htaccess is at "htdocs/wpx/". Is this where I am going wrong?

Comment: I just moved .htaccess to htdocs folder. Still the error persists. @avin

Comment: You are going in the wrong way htaccess must be inside wpx folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^context(.*) test.html
```

The systax means, whenever you hit the link `www.abc.com/context/` you will see the content from `www.abc.com/test.html`