# Create follow up page for the user

Tags: php, .htaccess

What I mean by that is, so lets say I have a page for the user itself: `localhost/blog/profile/ImUser1`

I want to have other pages for the user like:
`localhost/blog/profile/ImUser1/my_subscribers`
Or
`localhost/blog/profile/ImUser1/my_posts`

How do I create those kind of pages, like the subscriber page?

My current .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
CheckCaseOnly On
CheckSpelling On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ /blog/profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This allows for me to get to the userpage. And I need to have the username in the URL because thats how I extract information of who is subscribed to them.

Here is how I structured my PHP so far:

```
if(isset($_GET['username']) === true && empty($_GET['username']) === false){
    $username = $_GET['username'];

    if(user_exists($username) === true){
           echo 'Welcome to '.$username.' page!';
    }
}else{
           echo 'Please enter a username in the URL';
}
```

How do I tweak my PHP and .htaccess to make it work?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930849/php-url-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra query-string variable to the request for profile.php which specifies the mode. Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /blog/profile.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-z][a-z_]*)/?$ /blog/profile.php?username=$1&mode=$2 [L]
```

This way, a request for `/blog/profile/some_user/some_mode` will send the request to `profile.php?username=some_user&mode=some_mode` allowing your PHP script to check for a mode variable and render the page or redirect the page accordingly.

I've changed the username pattern from `(.*)` to `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` to stop it slurping up forward-slashes, and to require it to be at least one character in length. And I've used `[a-z][a-z_]*` for the mode pattern to require it to start with lowercase letters and then allow underscores.